# NDSolve problem with conservation laws

Tags: differential-equations

I am not an experienced Mathematica user, but decided to use it this time because of the in-buit special functions that it has.

My problem is a solution of the following ODE

```
y''[x]=-f(y[x]),  y'[0]=y'[L]=c,
```

with $L>0$, $c>0$, and periodic rhs $f(y+2\pi)=f(y)=-\Im\{\text{Li}_{2}(-e^{iy})\}$. I tried to solve the equation with the in-built `NDSolve` function and encountered the following problem.

Using the first integral of the above equation we find that

```
0.5*(y'[x])^2+F(y[x])=C,
```

where $C$ is a constant, and $F(y)=F(y+2\pi)$ such that $F'(y)=f(y)$. Using the boundary conditions we infer that

```
F(y[0])=F(y[L]),
```

implying that `y[L]=y[0]+2*Pi*n`. While solving the equation numerically with `NDSolve`, this property is not respected. In particular

```
s[L_, c_] := 
  NDSolve[{y''[x] == -Im[PolyLog[2, -E^(I*y[x])]], y'[
  0] == c, y'[L] == c}, y, {x, 0, L}];
a = s[5, 0.2];
Evaluate[y[5] /. a] - Evaluate[y[0] /. a]
```

gives me an output $5.02913$, which is not nearly a multiple of $2\pi$. My guess is that something is wrong with the quadrature. Can you help me please? Maybe I have to use a special method, like a shooting method, or something? If so then what is the deal, are there any caveats?

Best,
Kiryl

Comment: PS: I tried to use LaTeX for most of equations, but I kept getting an error, and found an advise here: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2593/cannot-post-question to write it as code instead

Answer (score 1):

Replacing one IC seems to work:

```
ClearAll[f, F, inv, sol]
f[w_?NumericQ] := Im[PolyLog[2, -E^(I*w)]]
F[w_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[t], {t, 0, w}] 
inv[w_?NumericQ, wp_?NumericQ]:= 0.5*wp^2+F[w]

sol[l_, c_] := NDSolve[
{wp[x] == w'[x], wp'[x] == -f[w[x]], wp[ 0] == c, Mod[Abs[w[0]  - w[l]], 2*Pi] == 0},
{w, wp},
{x, 0, l},
MaxStepFraction -> 0.01,
MaxSteps -> Infinity,
Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> Automatic}
];

out = sol[5, 0.2] // First ;
w[5] - w[0] /. out
{wp[0], wp[5]} /. out

F[w[5] /. out] - F[w[0] /. out]
Table[inv[w[x], wp[x]] /. out, {x, 0, 5, 0.5}]
```

I'd expect [projection](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveProjection.html) method to work here, but for some reason it throws an error:

```
sol[l_, c_] := NDSolve[
{wp[x] == w'[x], wp'[x] == -f[w[x]], wp[ 0] == c, wp[l] == c},
{w, wp},
{x, 0, l},
MaxStepFraction -> 0.01,
MaxSteps -> Infinity,
Method -> {"FixedStep", Method ->  {"Projection", Method -> Automatic,  "Invariants" ->{inv[w[x], wp[x]] }}}
];

out = sol[5, 0.2] // First ;
(* NDSolve::nnum1: The function value inv[w[0.],wp[0.]] is not a number when the arguments are {0.,{0.,0.}}.  *)
```

**Edit**

```
ClearAll[f, F, inv, sol]
f[w_?NumericQ] := Im[PolyLog[2, -E^(I*w)]]
F[w_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[t], {t, 0, w}]
inv[w_?NumericQ, wp_?NumericQ] := 0.5*wp^2 + F[w]

ClearAll[solution] ;
Options[solution] = {MaxStepFraction -> 0.005, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", 
     Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 10}}} ;
solution[l_, c_,  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  NDSolve[{wp[x] == w'[x], wp'[x] == -f[w[x]], wp[0] == c, 
     Mod[Abs[w[0] - w[l]], 2*Pi] == 0}, {w, wp}, {x, 0, l}, opts] /; 
   c >= 0 ;
solution[l_, c_,  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  NDSolve[{wp[x] == w'[x], wp'[x] == -f[w[x]], wp[l] == c, 
     Mod[Abs[w[0] - w[l]], 2*Pi] == 0}, {w, wp}, {x, 0, l}, opts] /; 
   c < 0 ;

out = solution[5, 0.2] // First;
{wp[0], wp[5]} /. out
Table[inv[w[x], wp[x]] /. out, {x, 0, 5, 1}]
(* {0.2`,0.19999537137167114`} *)
(* \
{-1.6718455006855417`,-1.6718458095149678`,-1.671842921367624`,-1.\
6718458808125778`,-1.6718464107564595`,-1.6718464264002912`} *)

out = solution[5, -0.2] // First;
{wp[0], wp[5]} /. out
Table[inv[w[x], wp[x]] /. out, {x, 0, 5, 1}]
(* {-0.19999537137418164`,-0.2000000000000036`} *)
(* \
{-1.6718464264011181`,-1.671846410757299`,-1.6718458808139036`,-1.\
6718429213688029`,-1.671845809516107`,-1.67184550068668`} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, very insightful! The problem is that with this method, the derivative at $L$ is sometimes negative $c$ and it has to be equal at $x=0$ and $x=L$

Comment: @KirylPesotski, indeed, see the edit, I still believe the project method to be a way to go, not sure why it is failing (guess it is related to the problem being bvp)